# Move variable value from function to other function JS

Tags: javascript, function, variables, callback

How Can I move variable value from function a to function b bacause I want create simple registration and login in console. I try do it from 6 hours, but I don't have idea. I was reading something about callback, but it doesn't work. Please help me, this is my code:

```js
function shell(comand){
const register = function(nick, login, password){
        nick = prompt("Type nick: ");
        login = prompt("Type login: ");
        password = prompt("Type password: ");
    }
            
            console.log("Registration complete");
}

const signin = function(lognick, loglogin, logpasswd, reg) {
    lognick = prompt("Type nick: ");
    loglogin = prompt("Type login: ");
    logpasswd = prompt("Type password: ");
    
    if(loglogin ==  login && logpasswd == password){
        console.log("login complete");
    } else{
        console.log("Login or password is not correct");
    }
}

    if(comand == "register"){
        register();
    }
    
    if(comand == "login"){
        signin();
    }
    
    return "process ended";
}
```

Comment: In general, you move values between functions by `return`ing them or by passing them as arguments, but in your case it looks like what you're actually after is to *preserver variable values between multiple calls* to that `shell` function. The solution to that would be declaring the variables outside of the function, and assigning to them.

Comment: Global variables? I thought about this, but I was hearing that isn't a good way. Thanks, I will do that. I'm sorry for my question, I learn js and I know only simple basis. Thank again.

Comment: Well, only if `shell` is also a global function :-) Yes, it's not optimal, but can be excused for very simple scripts and learning exercises. Next step would be putting them together in an object, not three separate variables - the first step to properly modularising the application. After all, it's still global state though.

Comment: I change my code, but I still have a problem, because I have one function (shell) and in her are two condisionals if: if(comand == "register") and if(comand == "login"), but variables values are other. In the first if variables values are correct, but when I typed (login), this values are set on undefined and condisional if(loglogin == login && logpasswd == password) never will be true. So I understood, that in area if the same variables has other value than the same variables in other area if. I don't know Do you understood me,because It was hard typing than paste code,but I can't paste code.

Comment: This is code (not working) `function shell(comand){
if(comand == "register"){
var nick = prompt("Type n: ");
var login = prompt("Type l: ");
var password = prompt("Type p: ");
if(nick == login){
while(nick == login){
nick = prompt("Type n: ");
login = prompt("Type l: ");
password = prompt("Type p: ");
}}
console.log("correct");}
if(comand == "login") {
let loglogin = prompt("Type login: ");
let logpasswd = prompt("Type password: ");
if(loglogin == login && logpasswd == password){
console.log("correct");
} else{
console.log("It's not correct");
}}
}`